Get multiple records for each day with a start and end date from existing 1 record
SiteSlot table is having start date and end date
Example:

Expected Output should be like below

We don't have any specified start date and end date and everything will be dynamic dates from the table
Need to convert 1 record into multiple records of each day

As per the question guide, please do not post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

And please show us your attempt.

You can create a calendar table which has all the dates and then join against it to create the records missing

You can use GENERATE_SERIES to get multiple rows. Made a bit more complicated by the fact you want the last enddate to be the same rather than the next day.
SELECT 
    SiteSlotId,
    DATEADD(day, g.value, startdate) AS startdate,
    DATEADD(day, g.value + IIF(DATEDIFF(day, startdate, enddate) = g.value, 0, 1), startdate) AS enddate
FROM SiteSlot ss
CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(0, DATEDIFF(day, startdate, enddate)) g;


WITH DateRange AS (
SELECT 
    SiteSlotId,
    startdate AS Date
FROM SiteSlot
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    SiteSlotId,
    DATEADD(DAY, 1, Date)
FROM DateRange
WHERE DATEADD(DAY, 1, Date) <= (SELECT enddate FROM SiteSlot WHERE SiteSlot.SiteSlotId = DateRange.SiteSlotId)) SELECT 
SiteSlotId, 
Date AS startdate,
Date AS enddate FROM DateRange ORDER BY SiteSlotId, startdate OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0);


Is this an answer? Or should it be part of your question? Either way, please use the code formatting option of the editor.

A good answer explains how the solution works as well; code dump answers can be poorly received (this one has already received 1 down vote).

Not to mention, an rCTE will not be a quick(est) way to do this for large date ranges.
